# How to get the saved Appointment on a DevExpress Scheduler control using WPF and MVVM?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, devexpress

I'm trying to implement a scheduler in WPF using the DevExpress `SchedulerControl`. What I want to do is at the moment of creating a new appointment, pass the new appointment object to the view model to save it in a database. This is my `MainWindow` view:

```xml
<Grid>
   <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
      <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
      <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
   </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
   <dxsch:SchedulerControl x:Name="scheduler" ActiveViewType="WeekView" FirstDayOfWeek="Monday" Grid.Column="0">
      <dxsch:SchedulerControl.OptionsWindows>
         <dxsch:OptionsWindows AppointmentWindowType="{x:Type local:CrearTareaWindow}"/>
      </dxsch:SchedulerControl.OptionsWindows>
      <dxmvvm:Interaction.Behaviors>
         <dxmvvm:EventToCommand EventName="AppointmentAdded" Command="{Binding SaveCommand}" />
         <dxmvvm:EventToCommand Command="{Binding DeleteCommand}" EventName="AppointmentRemoved"/>
         <dxmvvm:EventToCommand Command="{Binding EditCommand}" EventName="AppointmentEdited" />
      </dxmvvm:Interaction.Behaviors>
      <dxsch:SchedulerControl.DataSource>
         <dxsch:DataSource AppointmentsSource="{Binding Tareas}">
            <dxsch:DataSource.AppointmentMappings>
               <dxsch:AppointmentMappings
                  Subject="nombre"
                  Description="descripcion"
                  Start="fechaInicio"
                  End="fechaFin">
                  <dxsch:CustomFieldMapping Mapping="custom" Name="custom" />
               </dxsch:AppointmentMappings>
            </dxsch:DataSource.AppointmentMappings>
         </dxsch:DataSource>
      </dxsch:SchedulerControl.DataSource>
   </dxsch:SchedulerControl>
   <dxe:DateNavigator Name="dateNavigator" Grid.Column="1" ShowTodayButton="False">
      <dxe:DateNavigator.StyleSettings>
         <dxsch:SchedulerDateNavigatorStyleSettings Scheduler="{Binding ElementName=scheduler}" />
      </dxe:DateNavigator.StyleSettings>
   </dxe:DateNavigator>
</Grid>
```

Here I'm calling 3 commands whenever in the scheduler the user adds, deletes or edits a appointment.
My ViewModel looks like this:

```
public class ViewModel: ViewModelBase {
  public List < Tarea > Tareas {
    get =>new List < Tarea > {
      new Tarea {
        nombre = "Cita con el doctor",
        descripcion = "Al PPL le duele la panza",
        fechaInicio = new DateTime(2020, 10, 1, 12, 0, 0),
        fechaFin = new DateTime(2020, 10, 1, 14, 0, 0)
      }
    };
  }

  public ICommand SaveCommand {
    get {
      return new RelayCommand(param =>Save(param));
    }
  }
  void Save(object a) {
    Console.Write(a);
  }

  public ICommand DeleteCommand {
    get {
      return new RelayCommand(param =>Delete(param));
    }
  }
  void Delete(object a) {
    Console.Write("");
  }

  public ICommand EditCommand {
    get {
      return new RelayCommand(param =>Edit(param));
    }
  }
  void Edit(object a) {
    Console.Write(a);
  }
}
```

I'm using a custom window to save appointments:

```xml
<StackPanel Margin="10">
   <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold" Text="Nombre:"/>
   <TextBox Text="{Binding Subject, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
   <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold" Text="Descripción:"/>
   <TextBox Text="{Binding Description, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}" Height="100"/>
   <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold" Text="Fecha de Inicio:"/>
   <DockPanel>
      <dxe:DateEdit
             x:Name="editorStartDate"
             Width="150"
             DockPanel.Dock="Left"
             Style="{DynamicResource {dxscht:AppointmentWindowThemeKey ResourceKey=Editor_StartDate}}" />
      <dxe:TextEdit
             x:Name="editorStartTime"
             Margin="4,0,0,0"
             DockPanel.Dock="Left"
             Style="{DynamicResource {dxscht:AppointmentWindowThemeKey ResourceKey=Editor_StartTime}}" />
   </DockPanel>
   <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold" Text="Fecha de fin:"/>
   <DockPanel>
      <dxe:DateEdit
             x:Name="editorEndDate"
             Width="150"
             DockPanel.Dock="Left"
             Style="{DynamicResource {dxscht:AppointmentWindowThemeKey ResourceKey=Editor_EndDate}}" />
      <dxe:TextEdit
             x:Name="editorEndTime"
             Margin="4,0,0,0"
             DockPanel.Dock="Left"
             Style="{DynamicResource {dxscht:AppointmentWindowThemeKey ResourceKey=Editor_EndTime}}" />
   </DockPanel>
   <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold" Text="Custom:"/>
   <TextBox Text="{Binding CustomFields.custom, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
   <Grid Margin="0 10">
      <Grid.Resources>
         <Style TargetType="Button">
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0 0 10 0"/>
         </Style>
      </Grid.Resources>
      <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
         <ColumnDefinition/>
         <ColumnDefinition/>
         <ColumnDefinition/>
      </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
      <Button Grid.Column="0" Content="GUARDAR" Command="{Binding SaveAndCloseAppointmentCommand}"/>
      <Button Grid.Column="1" 
             Content="BORRAR" 
             CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=scheduler, Path=SelectedAppointments[0]}"
             Command="{Binding RemoveAppointmentCommand}"/>
      <Button Grid.Column="2" Content="CANCELAR" Command="{Binding CancelEditingCommand}"/>
   </Grid>
</StackPanel>
```

The problem is that I don't found a way to pass the created, edited or delete appointment to the command as parameter. I don't found nothing related in the documentation. The commands is called correctly when I add or delete but I don't found a way to get the appointment object that is added or deleted. How can I do this?

**SOLUTION UPDATE**

The first solution of that guy worked fine but I had problems with the second one. The problem is that AppointmentItem don't have a DataContext property so I have to do some changes to the converter:

```
protected override object Convert(object sender, AppointmentAddedEventArgs args) {
  AppointmentItem appointmentItem = args.Appointments.FirstOrDefault();
  Tarea tarea = new Tarea {
    nombre = appointmentItem.Subject,
    descripcion = appointmentItem.Description,
    fechaInicio = appointmentItem.Start,
    fechaFin = appointmentItem.End,
    EtiquetaId = (int ? ) appointmentItem.LabelId,
    custom = appointmentItem.CustomFields["custom"].ToString()
  };
  return tarea;
}
```

And in the ViewModel just take the Appointment object like this:

```
void Save(object a) {
  Tarea tarea = (Tarea) a;
  Console.Write(tarea);
}
```

With this I get the added appointment in the ViewModel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each of the events has an associated event args type.

- [`AppointmentAddedEventArgs`](https://docs.devexpress.com/WPF/DevExpress.Xpf.Scheduling.SchedulerControl.AppointmentAdded#event-data)
- [`AppointmentEditedEventArgs`](https://docs.devexpress.com/WPF/DevExpress.Xpf.Scheduling.SchedulerControl.AppointmentEdited#event-data)
- [`AppointmentRemovedEventArgs`](https://docs.devexpress.com/WPF/DevExpress.Xpf.Scheduling.SchedulerControl.AppointmentRemoved#event-data)

These event args each contain a collection of affected appointments in the `Appointments` property. You can pass these event args as `CommandParameter` automatically by setting [`PassEventArgsToCommand="True"`](https://docs.devexpress.com/WPF/17369/mvvm-framework/behaviors/predefined-set/eventtocommand#passing-a-parameter-to-the-bound-command), e.g.:

```
<dxmvvm:EventToCommand EventName="AppointmentAdded"
                       Command="{Binding SaveCommand}"
                       PassEventArgsToCommand="True"/>
```

Now, you could just cast the object passed to the corresponding command to the associated event args type and access the `Appointments` property, e.g. for added appointments:

```
void Save(object a) {
   var args = (AppointmentAddedEventArgs)a;
   var appointments = args.Appointments;
   
   // ...do something with the appointments.
}
```

This solves your problem, but is not good, as the event args are user interface related an should not be passed into the view model. However, there is a solution to this, as you can create an event args converter. See an example in the [documentation](https://docs.devexpress.com/WPF/17369/mvvm-framework/behaviors/predefined-set/eventtocommand#getting-started-with-eventtocommand).

You would create a converter for the target event type. As the `Appointments` collection contains [`AppointmentItem`](https://docs.devexpress.com/WPF/DevExpress.Xpf.Scheduling.AppointmentAddedEventArgs.Appointments) items, which are UI containers, you could extract your underlying data items of type `Tarea` with Linq by returning their `SourceObject` like this.

```
public class AppointmentAddedEventArgsConverter : EventArgsConverterBase<AppointmentAddedEventArgs>
{
   protected override object Convert(object sender, AppointmentAddedEventArgs args)
   {
      return args.Appointments.Select(ai => ai.SourceObject).Cast<Tarea>();
   }
}
```

Then you can assign it in XAML like this and it will automatically pass an enumerable of your `Tarea` items as command parameter to your command.

```
<dxmvvm:EventToCommand EventName="AppointmentAdded"
                       Command="{Binding SaveCommand}">
   <dxmvvm:EventToCommand.EventArgsConverter>
      <local:AppointmentAddedEventArgsConverter />
   </dxmvvm:EventToCommand.EventArgsConverter>
<dxmvvm:EventToCommand/>
```

In your execute delegate, you can directly cast the command parameter to the extracted item collection.

```
void Save(object a) {
   var addedTareas = (IEnumerable<Tarea>)a;

   // ...do something with the added items.
}
```

Comment: The first solution worked smoothly, but I had problems with the second one. AppointmentItem don't have a DataContext property, I don't know if it's because my DevExpress version or I use a different Reference and Import. I will put my approach in the answer.

Comment: @PaulMiranda I just noticed, that `AppointmentItem` does not derive from `FrameworkElement` and does not have a data context. Can you try the `SourceObject` property instead of `DataContext`?

Comment: It worked! Using the `SourceObject` of the `AppointmentItem` I can obtain the added item. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I also posted this question I have with DevExpress if you know the answer you will help me a lot! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64250567/how-to-show-custom-labels-and-status-on-custom-appointment-window-using-wpf-deve